# A next page function with shortcode?

Tags: php, functions, shortcode

I'm trying to create a next page function in php that's also a shortcode.

The code creates a next page link.

But the link appears above all the content (instead of where I put the shortcode), and doesn't wrap in the classes I attached to it.

```
function rk_post_nav_next($atts, $content = null)  {

    $link_to_send = next_post_link('%link', 'Next &raquo');

    $string = '<nav class="nav-single">';
    $string .= '<div class="nav-next">';
    $string .= $link_to_send;
    $string .= '</div></nav>';

    return $string;
}

add_shortcode( 'rk_post_nav_next', 'rk_post_nav_next' );
```

Answer (score 0):

`next_post_link()` doesn't return the output, prints, use [`get_next_post_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_next_post_link/) in your shortcode.